# Can't select first-child in this nodelist of 33 elements

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I'll explain this one in picture form:

[image]

As you can see there are 23 matching nodes here.

How do I get the first one? You would think:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vdatetimeCal > div > .cell.day:not(.day-header):nth-of-type(1)')
```

But no...

Empty node list returned!

A quick look at the HTML offers some clues:

[image]

Ah ha - So... guess what:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vdatetimeCal > div > .cell.day:not(.day-header):nth-of-type(8)')
```

This works!

Can anyone explain what is going on here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.vdatetimeCal > div > .cell.day:not(.day-header)
```

Returns the `cell` `day`s not having `day-header`. However, the pseudo-class of [nth-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) specifies the index of the tag type in its parent. Your first selector has two mutually-exclusive pseudo-classes, because `nth-of-type(1)` yields a `div` having the `class` of `day-header` which is excluded by `:not`. `nth-of-type(8)` works, because the pseudo-classes you use don't filter out that `span`.

Comment: Awesome. It was the "in its parent" bit that I hadn't understood. Thank you.